# Creating a sticky sidebar with javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, viewport

I am new to front end web development, so please forgive me if this is a novice question
I would like to create a sticky sidebar that appears when the parent div is inside the viewport, and disappears when it is out. Have a look at CSS tricks (how they create sticky ads on the right side which appear once there is space)
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLYVV.gif)

I cannot use position:sticky or position:fixed in css as I need browser compatibility, IE etc AND the `div` should not be fixed on the screen at all times, just until the end of its parent.

Clarification:  When the div enters the viewport, the sidebar should appear. I don't want the sidebar to be fixed for the whole page.

My layout is something like this:

```html
<div class="section">
  <div class="sidebar left">
    Sidebar
  </div>
  <div class="content">
    Text here
  </div>
</div>
Further content here...
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: *cannot use css as I need browser compatibility* - you're not going to do this without *any* css - perhaps a misunderstanding of what css is/does? Possibly state which browser you need compatibility for, eg `position:sticky` can't be used if you *really* still need IE11

Comment: @freedomn-m IE7-11 supports `position: fixed` just fine

Comment: @freedomn-m I did - oh snap you right, sorry

Answer (score 1):

> I cannot use CSS as I need browser compatibility.

You can and you should. `position: fixed` is [well supported across all the browsers](https://caniuse.com/css-fixed).

There is a basic example below:

```
<div class="side-bar">You content</div>
```

```
.side-bar {
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 200px;
  max-width: 100vw; /* don't let your blow be wider that screen */
}
```

Comment: The div should not be fixed on the screen at all times, just until the end of its parent.

Answer (score 1):

First you should give a hidden class to that div element to make it disappear. Add this code to your *CSS* file:

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

And the HTML file would look like this:

```
<div class="div1">Some content</div>
<div class="div2 hidden">Some other content</div>
```

After that you need to use an API called ***IntersectionObserver*** in your script(javascript) file like this:

```
const div1 = document.querySelector('.div1');   // The top div in the HTML file

const div2 = document.querySelector('.div2');   // The bottom div in the HTML file

const observerCallback = function (entries) {
   if (!entries[0].isIntersecting) div2.classList.remove('hidden');
   else div2.classList.add('hidden');
}

const observerOptions = { root: null, threshold: 0};

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(observerCallback, observerOptions);
observer.observe(div1);
```

These codes will point to the two divs:

```
const div1 = document.querySelector('.div1');

const div2 = document.querySelector('.div2');
```

And this code will create an IntersectionObserver that will observe for div1 element:

```
const observer = new IntersectionObserver(observerCallback, observerOptions);
observer.observe(div1);
```